# How can I open the Google Chrome Console from JavaScript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The question might sound weird but I kind of need this to happen. The alternative would be to ask people to press Ctrl+Shift+i but I would prefer to avoid that and just provide a link.

The link would show up in a Chrome Extension so I'm only interested for Google Chrome.

Comment: [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension?rq=1)

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, not likely to happen (except as a security hole). Your in-page JavaScript is deliberately sandboxed and limited - it can interact with the page, and with the network through AJAX, but it cannot and should not interact with other things that happen in your computer - including the browser.

Comment: I believe Claudiu is referring to Javascript as executed by the Chrome extension, not by any particular page's environment. Extensions have both richer API and bigger permissions (according to the plug-in's manifest file), IIRC.

Comment: Interesting since you would only open, not edit it. And someone could just fake the input anyways..

Answer (score 11):

It is not clear why you need to provide such link.
DevTools is not a tool for the end user.
If you don't like keyboard shortcuts, then there is a page chrome://inspect/ which has the list of pages and extensions, and each entry has a link that opens devtools.

Also, you may use remote debugging page which opens devtools in a page.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: chrome://inspect/ is using `chrome.send('inspect',[String(data.processId), String(data.routeId)]);` maybe this could lead to a solution

Comment: http://blog.poweredbytoast.com/googles-undocumented-quotchromesendquot-command

Comment: Well, I see this request similar to `debugger;`, but something that opens console instead of debugger tool. A use case I have is, for coding tools like codepen, openprocessing, to show errors and links for users to check their console:  "Hey the code you wrote has a bug, see it in console. Open Console"  etc.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried Firebug Lite. It is an in-browser tool similar to that found in Chrome.

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

It will give you most of the capabilities you are looking for (most likely), and will allow you to programmatically enable it and destroy it.

What do you think?