# Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have a chrome extension which hooks into the devtools.  Ideally I want a badge that, when clicked, opens up the devtools on the new tab which I created.  Is there any way to do this from the background page?

Comment: where you able to find an answer to the problem?

Comment: This would still be really nice wouldn't it - any updates?

Comment: I've posted (and will be adding a bounty to) a related, but slightly different, question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660325/open-safari-google-chrome-developer-tools-programmatically-from-javascript

Comment: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311191/how-to-open-chrome-developer-console-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: In case you're curious like me what Chrome uses itself to open the devtools when you click the "backgroung page" link on an extension page, it's [`chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/developerPrivate#method-openDevTools)

Answer (score 35):

It seems unlikely that this is possible or will ever become possible,

check this:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277

which says:
"We only allow explicit devtools opening."

Comment: Indeed they recently [re-confirmed the decision](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/476#issuecomment-1804251490) to not allow programmatic opening of the dev tools.

Comment: see also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=445240

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can (or not) using the experimental APIs `chrome.experimental.webInspector`.
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html
You can even change the content and panels of it.
Note that you will not able submit extensions that use experimental APIs.

Comment: However, it's worth noting that you can [host these outside of the extensions gallery](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html) if you are determined. Although this would mean that users would also have to use the [dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) and enable the [Experimental Extension APIs flag](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.html#using).

Comment: [`experimental.webInspector`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.webInspector.html) is now called [`chrome.experimental.devtools`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.devtools.html). Some of the APIs are not experimental any more, and they are listed under [`chrome.devtools`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/devtools.html). **Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically open the Dev tools** via a Chrome extension.

Comment: @Rob W, Didn't notice `chrome.devtools.*` APIs have become outside of experiment APIs.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do that.

The `chrome://chromewebdata` link only works if an instance of DevTools is already opened.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite old but since I stumbled upon it now searching for a solution I figured others might have too. Since Chrome 28 you can use the [devtools.*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) API. This allows you to open and manipulate DevTools panels. It is also notable no longer expirimental.

Comment: Do you remember what method is used to progammatically open the devtools from the background script? All other answers (from stackoverflow) seem to suggest that it's impossible...

Comment: @Sentero-esp12 just click right button on needed page and select "Inspect" from it)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The devtools.* APIs are for building extensions to the developer tools. They don't provide a way to launch it programatically. And the question was how to do it programmatically, so "just click right" isn't an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One could try

`chrome.developerPrivate.openDevTools`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the extension could kick off a Selenium script and you could use the "send_keys()" function as something like this:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).\
            send_keys('J').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

... as "Ctrl+Shift+J" is the default keybind to open dev-tools (as of Jul 08, 2021)

Comment: Could provide more details on this and how to use these scripts?

Comment: @emvaized sure thing, sorry for the wait just saw this;
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make a script that simulates a `CRTL+ALT+J` which opens the devtools but it didn't work. After that I found this:
It is not possible due to security restrictions. Browsers do not allow scripts to programmatically open the console or trigger certain keyboard shortcuts for security reasons. These restrictions are in place to prevent malicious activities.
If you need to interact with the console, you can do that only manually, or use the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

I hear you're trying to crack the DevTools code with your extension, but unfortunately, it's not as simple as a "whiz, bang, poof" kind of situation.

Think of DevTools as the browser's super secret clubhouse, and extensions are kind of like the neighborhood kids. Sure, they're curious about what's inside, but the clubhouse leader (aka, security) has put up a big "No Peeking!" sign for a reason. It's all about keeping everyone's browsing safe and sound.

So, why the no-go on programmatic DevTools access for extensions? Here's the scoop:

- **Safety first:** Imagine any extension could just waltz into the clubhouse and start snooping around. Talk about privacy nightmares! Keeping your browsing info under wraps is top priority.
- **You're the captain of your ship:** You deserve to decide when the DevTools curtain raises, not some rogue extension. It's your browser, your rules!
- **Stability matters:** Messing with DevTools unexpectedly can be like poking a grumpy bear – things might get messy, and nobody wants a browser meltdown, right?

Now, all that doesn't mean you're stuck in the DevTools dark ages. Here are some alternative paths to try:

- **Channel your inner keyboard ninja:** Try sending virtual keystrokes like "Ctrl+Shift+I" to open DevTools. It's not foolproof, but it might work depending on your extension.
- **Become your own debugging hero:** Maybe your extension can offer its own built-in detective tools instead of relying on DevTools. Think of it as creating your own mini-clubhouse, just for your extension!
- **Level up your game:** If you really need programmatic access, consider building a full-fledged browser extension, not just a Chrome one. It's more work, but it gives you more keys to the kingdom (and DevTools!).

Remember, security is like the magic password to the DevTools clubhouse. While bypassing it might seem tempting, it's ultimately there to protect you and your browsing experience. So, keep coding with confidence, knowing your browser secrets are safe and sound!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible with side extension, but if the reason is that you've tired to click Ctrl + Shift + I again and again every time - you can simply open the right button menu on needed page and select "Inspect" from it, it'll open the console like extension button, and also you don't need to search for its icon every time you need it, which is more conviniently than using an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Content Script:

In your extension's manifest file (manifest.json), define a content script that will run on the target tab.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "DevTools Opener",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Open DevTools",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Content Script (content.js):

In your content script, use the following code to open the DevTools programmatically.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "openDevTools") {
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("DevToolsAPI.showPanel('console')", function (result, isException) {
      if (isException) {
        console.error("Failed to open DevTools:", isException);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Background Page:

Handle the badge click in the background page.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "openDevTools" });
});
```

his background page code assumes that you're sending a message to the content script to open DevTools. The content script, in turn, uses chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval to execute a script in the context of the DevTools page.

Comment: the is no chrome.devtools in content scripts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can programmatically open the DevTools in a Google Chrome extension using the **chrome.devtools** API. The **chrome.devtools.panels** module provides methods for interacting with DevTools panels.

Comment: show exactly how. I don't see. there's setOpenResourceHandler, but that's not for arbitrary panels. see also the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388691/11107541