# Can chrome extension control tabs and the devtool?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

1. can it add new tab?
2. can it control the size of the tab
3. can it control the url of the tab even 10 min after you open it?
4. can it focus on a specific tab
5. can it access the devtools?

same questions regarding chrome windows

can it take few windows and sum them all up to one window with many tabs?

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes. [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)
2. Yes. [`chrome.windows.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-update)
3. Yes. [`chrome.tabs.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update)
4. Yes. [`chrome.tabs.update`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update)
5. Yes and No. The developer tools [cannot be opened by an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension/6822670#comment12311571_6822670), but you can add panels to the Dev tools using the [`devtools.*`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/devtools.html) API.

[`chrome.windows.getAll`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-getAll) can be used to get a collection of all [Windows](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#type-Window). Each Window has a property `tabs`, which holds properties of to the [Tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab).

Comment: @micha I have reverted your edit, because the question contained 5 numbered questions.

Comment: sorry I didn't looked at the question when I found your great answer.