# Is there a way to activate the chrome inspector from javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

I'd like to trigger the chrome inspector by clicking a button on a webpage - I'm building a Chrome devtools extension.

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension ?