# Can I open Chrome Developer Tools with an anchor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I realize Chrome Developer tools are just HTML elements like any other.

Simple question... is this possible?

```
<a href='#' onclick='openDevTools()'>Open Chrome Developer Tools</a>
```

What would `openDevTools()` contain?

Obviously I know shortcut keys exist.

Comment: It's doubtful .. but do you have something against F12?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension

Comment: @nbrooks: Watch http://goo.gl/Qp6Xj

Comment: @Jordan Coool, never knew that, thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

No, for security reasons you cannot open built-in DevTools window programmatically.

Comment: This hard to believe given that Dev Tools are just HTML elements: http://goo.gl/Qp6Xj -- where's your source?

Comment: It is true that DevTool front-end is actually a web application and you can load it manually by typing chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html in the address bar. However, opening URLs with chrome-*:// protocol is blocked for regular pages so you cannot do e.g. window.open("chrome-devtools://devtools/devtools.html")

To inspect another page DevTools front-end uses special APIs that are not available to regular web pages. The same front-end can be used for remote debugging in which case the API is exposed via a web socket.