# Javascript-How to enable Debugger automatically on load of the page in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page(firstpage.html), my requirement is on load of that HTML (firstpage.html)
in browser it should automatically enable the debugger for the page. So is there any way so that i can enable  debugger automatically by using some java script code on my html page?

Thank You.
Regards,
Preetish.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    debugger;
});
```

That's vanilla for the famous jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){...});`—it executes the contained code upon completion of the DOM loading.

Comment: Unfortunately, `debugger;` does not seem to do anything if devtools is not already open.

Comment: True, of course. OP should have Chrome Dev Tools open before loading the page (or before reloading).

Comment: Sure, but the OP seems to want to have it opened automatically for him.

Comment: Ah. OP doesn't use the word "open", only "enable", but I wonder now…

Comment: See also https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112277.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660325/open-safari-google-chrome-developer-tools-programmatically-from-javascript.

Comment: Yes, it would seem an odd request to give JS code the ability to open my Dev Tools (or to perform similar browser modifications).