# How to open Chrome Developer Tools in a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to open Chrome Developer Tools to inspect a Chrome App ?

Comment: If you want to open Chrome developer tools programmatically, it's impossible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660325/open-safari-google-chrome-developer-tools-programmatically-from-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All debuggable targets are listed under `chrome://inspect/`. See the 'Apps' tab.

[image: chrome://inspect page]

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it by following instructions to debug [postman chrome app](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/enabling-chrome-developer-tools-inside-postman/):

- Go to `chrome://flags/`
- Search for ***Debugging for packed apps***
- Enable this flag
- Restart chrome

Then go to your app, `right-click` anywhere inside of it, and click on the option menu `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

To open it by context menu, enable at chrome://flags/#debug-packed-apps

If the app blocks the context menu, find it at chrome://extensions (developer mode) or the [Apps and Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc).