# javascript code to launch debugger

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wondering if javascript not a command to launch browser debugger same as c#,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

For the life of me, I want to put a single command in javascript code to pause debugger on that, it is so useful for productivity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
debugger;
```

Javascript will always stop if you reach this point of code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger