# Link to DevTools F12

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I just wondered if there is an opportunity to open the DevTools (in IE,Chrome,FF) via JavaScript or similar?

I found a couple of Questions about Chrome here on SO but they al say ist not possible.

I thought maybe you there is a way to through a keypress Event for F12?

Comment: Nope sorry. You are pretty sandboxed in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: What is the use case for having a link in a website open the developer tools?

Comment: @isherwood I have seen that article before, but Im not talking about a Chrome Extension

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thats a good Question :)

Comment: @j_s_stack If it can't be done from a chrome extension, it can't be done from a webpage.

Comment: I dont now about C. extensions so, yeah was just a question

Answer (score 0):

In IE it isn't possible to launch the F12 tools from the page. It is possible, but ugly and not useful, if you write an extension to IE.

If you find a way, let us know as it would be a bug :). We mainly limit the scenario as we don't want a malicious script or similar to expand the surface area for an attack programmatically.