# Auto open Chrome Dev Tools for new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code for a Chrome Extension

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('dist/index.html')});
```

is there an option I can add to this call, so that Dev Tools is automatically opened when the tab is created?

looks like there is a command line flag for a Chrome for a new window:

```
--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
```

but not sure if this applies for single tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is no way to do this now, and unlikely will ever become possible.

It seems like it was experimental API few years ago, but now it's removed.

For more information check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension).

Comment: maybe there is a way to programmatically open dev tools once the page has loaded?

Comment: As I know, there is no way to do this :( However, You can get programmatic access to the [devtools](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-chrome-developer-tools/beDuY1DGZRA/2Q8ynmc7CAAJ).

Comment: hmmm couldn't you just find the element on the page that has dev tools and click it somehow? or maybe that's outside of the window scope...seems really strange, maybe it's for security reasons

Comment: I don't know the way to do this :(
I would suggest to check [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and [devtools-protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), maybe you will find some ideas or useful information there.