# Open web console in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-console

Is it possible to open the client's web console in javascript (CTRL+SHIFT+K on Firefox)? Define the size, the position, else?

Thank you

Comment: You just said that you only have to press Ctrl+Shift+K, so it appears to be possible indeed?

Comment: @Bergi simulating those keypresses through JavaScript won't open the client's console, though

Comment: I honestly hope not.  I wouldn't want a malicious site to be able to force my dev tools open or try to trick my mother into thinking that all those console error messages mean that she has a virus and that she needs to provide her CC details right now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this being possible, and I couldn't find anything in a recent search about how to do it either.  I did find another stackoverflow conversation about something similar here: [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

From that, I surmise that if it's not possible from a browser extension, it seems even less likely to be possible from plain JavaScript.