# How to open DevTools with chrome API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Say I have this:

```
   chrome.tabs.create({}, function(tab){

   });
```

I am looking at the options for the first argument - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

there doesn't seem to be an option to have DevTools open automatically, but I am wondering if there is not a method on the tab, to open DevTools, something like this:

```
   chrome.tabs.create({}, function(tab){
        tab.openDevTools();
   });
```

is this possible somehow?

Comment: No, it's not possible now. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the info, i might delete this question then - do you happen to know anything about this btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755724/use-chrome-devtools-panels-create-in-chrome-extension-content-script