# Use `chrome.devtools.panels.create()` in Chrome Extension content script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have this in a content-script:

```
  chrome.devtools.panels.create('Suman Extension Page Controls',
  'icon.png',
  'devtools-panel.html',
  function (panel) {
    console.log('my devtools panel.');

  });
```

however, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'panels' of undefined

I tried adding "devtools" to the permissions array in my manifest.json file, but that's not allowed.

Is there a way to use the devtools API from a content script? How do I dynamically add panels to DevTools on a random webpage?

Comment: note that I don't want to add a DevTools panel in my extension, I want the panel to be available for end users at almost any given webpage/url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's incorrect to use it from the content scripts, from the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools):

> The chrome.devtools.* API modules are available only to the pages
>   loaded within the DevTools window. Content scripts and other extension
>   pages do not have these APIs

You need to create separate `html` file, then set it to the `devtools_page` property in your `manifest`. And after that, you can load your scripts in this html file and create panel from here.

Good example of extension, which is does this - [React Dev Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/shells/webextension/src/main.js#L30).

Comment: thanks Sergey - I looked at the React example - so the devtools_page property will then add this devtools panel to every single page? ideally, I would just change devtools for certain pages.

Comment: No, they first check for `React` in the [content script](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/shells/webextension/src/checkForReact.js) and if they found any version of react on the page, only then they will [add a panel](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/shells/webextension/src/main.js#L17).

Comment: ahhhh I see, so once I add the `devtools_page` property to the manifest, then `chrome.devtools` will be defined in the content script

Comment: ok that didn't work...so I guess `chrome.devtools` is available only in scripts loaded by the `devtools_page`...

Comment: Yes, `chrome.devtools` available only from `devtools_page` page.

Comment: yeah it looks like my chrome-extension devtools_page gets invoked for every tab....so I make a new port/connection from my background page to  every chrome tab? seems like too many

Comment: It's an only way how to do it now :( 
From the performance perspective, with port/connection to every chrome tab will be no problem.

Comment: yeah, it says: "An instance of the devtools_page specified in your extension's manifest is created for every DevTools window opened." So not for every page, only for the pages where devtools is open...

Comment: Hey Sergey - the way to communicate between the content script and the devtools page, is via the background script? Or can we communicate *directly* between content script and devtools page?

Comment: can I create the panel later? It means when the devtool opened the panel will not be created until I execute some method which is set by cotent_script like window.createPanel = ()=>chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'createPanel'}). and the devtoll page have `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addEventListener` this callback to handle create panel. I have done this way but it not work