# Do we have any javascript function with html where we can open the developer tool in the Chrome browser automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools

```
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" onKeyPress="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}


</script>

</body>
```

found this code where in i need to press f12 inside the input box, please let me know if there is any code to automate this (When chrome opens automatically the developer tool should open)

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) something you're looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Simply, no. Why you want user to open devtools anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I know of - if anyone proposed this as a feature, it would probably be considered a security risk.