# How to read data transfer from dev tool via script?

Tags: javascript, iframe, request

Is there a way to read the value that is shown in the dev tool window at the bottom of the Network tab ?
[image: Brave's DevTool Network tab]

The reason I'm asking is that I need to watch some requests download status for a custom progress bar. The issue is that **I cannot** have access to the method that triggers these requests, because the method is written in a file during the build of our application (here Unity, using WebGL export), and this file cannot (or at least, not meat to) be edited or *templated*.

I know the request URL so I am able to know the full size of the downloaded file using the headers, but I need to know the state of the download itself so I can build a proper custom loading bar. Since it is shown in the dev tool I though it might not be too hard to read it from a script. But maybe I'm wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: Pretty sure it's a one-way-operation. Dev tools can read/process the browser environment but not the other way around. I don't think you can even [use a script to _open_ the dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension) which is a question that came up a while back.

Comment: Well, too bad. Thanks for the reply anyway ! Maybe I'll post another question with the actual problem explained.