# Force DevTools to Focus on an Particular Element in an iframe on Element Inspection

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

If I have an `iframe` in my page and I do Google Chrome Development Tools, Element Inspection, it selects the `html` by default via `#document`.

There is no way to auto launch the DevTools by default on click.

[Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)

Is there a way to set focus (as in the element is selected in DevTools) given that if I have

```
<iframe srcdoc="<h1></h1>"></iframe>
```

So basically when the user clicks on the element, the Devtools is launched (not possible) but atleast the element in question, `h1` is selected.

Comment: Since the element is automatically selected in normal iframes, it must be a bug in devtools for srcdoc.

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately you can't. Chrome consider iframe source as a different page entirely.

but there is a piece of information (I do not know how useful it is), when you right-click an element in Google Chrome it will give you the ability to `view frame source`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the same issue for iframes (HTML content loaded from other URL) used in react native.