# How do manually trigger the F12 (Developer Tool panel) on document click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody know How do manually trigger the F12 (Developer Tool panel) in Jquery or Javascript

I Tried using click event like this

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
   if(event.which === 123){
      //I do not know what code comes here
   }
});

$(document).trigger("click");
```

Anybody do research on this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575134/how-can-i-open-the-google-chrome-console-from-javascript

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - I am asking on document click

Comment: Imagine you visit a site that by just running `Browser.showDevTools()` the dev panel suddenly appeared. Wouldn't be stupidly annoying? That's why there are so many things you cannot do from Javascript in a generic browser. The user must have always control on what the page does.

Comment: @Claudix - Ok but i want this

Comment: @Sudharsan In the linked question, OP want to open the console while user is clicking on a link, you are trying to do that while user is pressing a key. Both are coming under same category right. And it does make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't press functional keys via javascript. 
I think we can trigger using .trigger() but can't get the same feature as pressing F12!

```
jQuery.trigger({ type: 'keypress', which: '123'}); // 123 for F12
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can not do this. as it is attached with browser and not with page. JS holds the power to communicate with page and making network calls. Not with browser and other events on machine.