# How to close console (devtools) programmatically from Extension?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to close the console (devtools) programmatically from Extension?

Comment: You cannot do that using code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do manually trigger the F12 (Developer Tool panel) on document click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949541/how-do-manually-trigger-the-f12-developer-tool-panel-on-document-click)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I programmatically open the devtools from a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801577/can-i-programmatically-open-the-devtools-from-a-google-chrome-extension)